# Developing Rails on OpenShift

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, openshift

im developing a Rails application on OpenShift... 
As I am getting some troubles installing Rails on my local PC, ive ssh to my openshift app and created the controllers from there.
I can access new controllers of the application, however I want my local gut copy of the app to get updated with the new controllers Ive created.
Ive tried both git fetch and pull:

```
$ git pull
Already up-to-date.
```

And git fetch shows no feedback.
However new controllers ive created are noy synchronizes localy.

How can I do this?
Do I have to use rhc client?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OpenShift is designed to interact with git from your client machine.  So from your client you should make your application changes.  Git add/commit/push and the changes will be published to the OpenShift server.  For Rails there are several easy ways to get started:

- Go to https://openshift.redhat.com/app/console/application_types and select Ruby on Rails (This will create a new app).  You can then integrate your previous changes with this app and delete the original app.  If you really want an app of the same name you can copy down your original changes first and delete the original app before creating this one.
- Use the quick start directly:  https://github.com/openshift/rails-example/ (You have already done step 1 and 2 from the instructions there).  If you go this route, you'll want to copy your changes you made on the OpenShift server to you local system and integrate it with the quick start code before the git push.  Once you git push the existing changes you made will be replaced by the code you are pushing from your client.
- Or you can do it yourself if you can get past your local Rails issues (Some searching for Rails and OpenShift will get a more detailed example):

From within your local git repo:

```
rails new app
cd app
bundle install
rails generate controller home index
git add .
git commit -a -m "Initial setup"
git push
```